# Methods of Merging layers/shapefiles using OGR in python

Tags: python, merge, layer, gdal, ogr

I am new to python and am trying to get more comfortable automating GIS tasks with python. Any help is appreciated

I have two layers containing points that I am trying to merge together into one single layer, using Ogr in python. Below is code I found on a website, however it is giving me an error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayer'

The line I believe that is causing this error is:

> ds = ogr.Open(directory + file)

I am wondering why nothing is generated at this step, and I am also wondering if there is a different/better approach to merging layers using gdal/ogr python

```
outputMergefn = 'Merge.shp'
directory = "C:/Users/Robin/Documents/Python Final Project/Final_Project/Output"
filestartswith = 'C'
FileEndsWith = '.shp'
drivername = 'ESRI Shapefile'
geometrytype = ogr.wkbMultiPoint
ptdriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

if os.path.exists(outputMergefn):
    ptdriver.DeleteDataSource(outputMergefn)
out_ds = ptdriver.CreateDataSource(outputMergefn)
out_layer = out_ds.CreateLayer(outputMergefn, geom_type = geometrytype)

filelist = os.listdir(directory)
for file in filelist:
    if file.startswith(filestartswith) and file.endswith(FileEndsWith):
        print file
        ds = ogr.Open(directory + file)
        if ds is None:
            print "This is None"
        lyr = ds.GetLayer()
        for feat in lyr:
            out_feat = ogr.Feature(out_layer.GetLayerDefn())
            out_feat.SetGeometry(feat.GetGeometryRef().Clone())
            out_layer.CreateFeature(out_feat)
            out_layer.SyncToDisk()
```

Comment: `None` is returned when you have an error. Put `ogr.UseExceptions()` near the top to see what the error is. It is probably that it could not find the dataset. Also, with OGR, you can open a directory of shapefiles as a single dataset with many layers for each shapefile.

Comment: Thanks Mike, you're right, I didn't add a "/" after Output in the directory I defined above. It runs fine now.

Comment: Can you post the final code and close the question please? I also want to merge shapefiles using OGR and it would be useful to see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the directory. In the directory you have specified, there does not exist a shapefile. That is why the `GetLayer()` function gives an error. Because according to the directory, the datasource should be shapefile, but due to error in directory, the datasource is not a shapefile (it might be a folder or some other file). And when the datasource is not a shapefile, then the function `GetLayer()` could not be used.